# Can you specify a semicolon-separated string as an implicit list to list(JOIN ...) in CMake?

Tags: cmake

My understanding is that in CMake, a semicolon-separated string is implicitly a list, which seems to be borne out by my example below:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ListJoin)

# Create a list from a "variadic list" of space-separated strings
set(list1 "foo" "bar" "baz")
list(JOIN list1 " " string1)
message("${list1}  -->  ${string1}")

# Create a list from a single semicolon-separated string
set (list2 "foo;bar;baz")
foreach(item ${list2})
  message("${item}")
endforeach()
list(JOIN list2 " " string2)
message("${list2}  -->  ${string2}")
```

```
$ cmake -B build
foo;bar;baz  -->  foo bar baz
foo
bar
baz
foo;bar;baz  -->  foo bar baz
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake-learn/list_join/build
```

**How can I supply an implicit list (semicolon-separated string) to `list(JOIN ...)` in order to join its members as a one-liner?**

I tried what seemed like the obvious conclusion of the above:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ListJoin)

# Supply a single semicolon-separated string to list(JOIN ...)
list(JOIN "lorem;ipsum;dolor" " " string3)
message("(implicit list)  -->  ${string3}")
```

```
$ cmake -B build
(implicit list)  -->
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake-learn/list_join/build
```

---

I understand that for the specific use-case above, I can perhaps simply create a space-separated string like this:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ListJoin)

set(string4 "foo bar baz")
message("(explicit string)  -->  ${string4}")
```

```
$ cmake -B build
(explicit string)  -->  foo bar baz
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake-learn/list_join/build
```

...but my broader goal is to understand CMake's rules about strings, lists, and semicolon-separated strings.

Comment: "my broader goal is to understand CMake's rules about strings, lists, and semicolon-separated strings" - One of the rule is that when [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html) specifies the parameter to be a **list**, then the parameter should contain a **name** of the variable which contains a list. Via that parameter you cannot pass an "inline" list.